# Overriding CalendarDateConverter in z3c.form

Tags: plone, z3c.form

z3c.form registers a converter like this:

```
<adapter
  factory=".converter.DatetimeDataConverter"
  />
```

Is it possible to override this converter in Plone using overrides.zcml? What kind of input one needs to give for overrides.zcml to override it? Should one copy interface matching definitons from .py code:

```
class DatetimeDataConverter(CalendarDataConverter):
    """A special data converter for datetimes."""
    zope.component.adapts(
        zope.schema.interfaces.IDatetime, interfaces.IWidget)
```

Any other non-monkey-patching means to override z3c.converters?

Answer (score 2):

I'd simply register the new converter for a more specific interface:

```
 <adapter
     factory=".myconverter.MyDatetimeDataConverter"
     for="zope.schema.interfaces.IDatetime
          z3c.form.interfaces.ITextWidget"
     />
```

I used `ITextWidget` as an example, register it for the widgets where you want your custom converter to be used.

Overrides replace adapters with the same registration. Just like the `<adapter />` registration in a regular ZCML file, it'll take the interface(s) it (multi-)adapts and the interface it provides from the factory object, if need be, so if you used `.adapts()` on your own converter then you do not need to repeat that information in the `<adapter />` registration.